# htaccess how to always have subdomain in url for every route

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5, server

I'm trying to set up my laravel project made on a local appache server on a internal shared hosting service of my university.

The problem I am having is that except for the routes related to my laravel projects Authorisation/Authentication (HomeController) stuff other routes do not work as the subdomain for those routes are not automatically added like this for them (bolded part being the subdomain):

> https://www.cs2410-web02pvm.aston.ac.uk/**~khane2**/home

Here is my web.php of my laravel project:

```
Route::get('/animal_user_change_status/{animal_id}/attach', 'Animal_usersController@attach');
Route::get('/animal_user_change_status/{animal_id}/{user_id}/detach', 'Animal_usersController@detach');
Route::get('/animal_user_change_status/{animal_id}/{user_id}/Accept', 'Animal_usersController@setAcceptToStatusColumn');
Route::get('/animal_user_change_status/{animal_id}/{user_id}/Reject', 'Animal_usersController@setRejectToStatusColumn');
Route::get('/viewuserdata', 'Animal_usersController@viewUserData');
Route::get('/viewanimalsdata', 'Animal_usersController@viewAnimalData');

Route::get('/', 'AnimalController@index'); // just incase anything redricts to '/'
Route::resource('Animal', 'AnimalController');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Here is my .../public_html/.htaccess from my server.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
 Options -MultiViews -Indexes
 </IfModule>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 # Handle Authorization Header
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 #Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
 RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
 #Handle Front Controller...
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(~[^/]+)(.*)
 RewriteRule ^ /%1/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You refer to "~khane2" as a "subdomain"? Just to fix the wording: this is a string as part of the path component of the URL. Strings with a leading tilde ("~") are usually interpreted as "user account name" by http servers which tells the server where to look for the content in the server side file system. This has _nothing_ to do with a host name (sometimes dubbed as a "subdomain").

Comment: This reads like your html content you generate uses absolute paths in the references, not relative ones as required. So something like `/foo/bar` instead of `foo/bar`.

Comment: !!! Thats it I've been using absolute paths !!!!! Thanks man!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could be of help.